# can we stop Service before it start in my android app?

Tags: android, android-service

what happen if i stop service where as there is not any service run in my android app.
does service check that there are any service is in running mode before stop.

Thanks

Comment: great atomic mushroom will appear on the sky

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the service is running or not using this:

```
public static boolean isYourServiceRunning(Context c) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) c
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (YourService.class.getName().equals(
                service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```